# wordnet api calling through c# for word search in dictionary

Tags: c#, api, wordnet

I need to use wordnet API in c# to search word in dictionary. I am collecting tweets from Pakistani region and they are mixture of English and Roman Urdu. I need to separate English tweets from Roman Urdu tweets. What is the best way of doing this? 
Can anyone help???????

Comment: I don't know about `wordnet` but laguage saperation is a complicated problem which can be approached in different ways. Some of the common ways are `Neural-Networks`, `Alpha-Bet occurences statistics` or simple word in dictionary search but when your polled data is small the later will have more mistake rate.

Comment: Roman Urdu contains words spelled with English Alphabets so i need to search those words in dictionary if found it means they belong to English and if not it means they are belong to Roman Urdu. Do you know any method of searching word in dictionary through c#.

Comment: Does it have to be wordnet, or any dictionary?

Comment: it could be any dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can download any dictionary, to which you can compare English words. when the word count of sentence is three that are not present in English dictionary you can assume it to be a roman sentence.